# Irreducible Representations of $<X,Y>/\{[X,Y]=Y\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I was doing exercises from Etingof's Introduction to Representation Theory and came across this problem.

$2.16.2$ Find all irreducible representations of the Lie algebra $L$ with generators $X$ and $Y$ and relation $[X,Y] = Y$. Do this for the positive and zero characteristic cases. Does the Lie theorem (is every finite-dimensional irrep one-dimensional) hold for positive characteristic?

It is simple to find that when $L$ is over an algebraically-closed field that the irreps are precisely one-dimensional vector spaces with $X$ and $Y$ as scalar and zero operators, respectively.

However, it seems that it is not true for either zero or positive characteristic fields in general since if the field is not algebraically-closed, then $X$ can have no eigenvalues and one can construct an irrep of dimension $> 1$ by setting $Y = 0$ and $X$ to be some eigenvalue-less operator.

It would be very helpful if someone could shed some light on this problem. Am I solving/reading it right, is the reasoning posted above sound? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a standing assumption in that book that the field of coefficients is assumed to be algebraically closed unless stated otherwise (see the beginning of section 1.2).

But over an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic, there are irreducible representations of dimension greater than $1$.

For example, suppose $\operatorname{char}(k)=2$, and let $V=k^2$, with $X$ acting by $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$, and $Y$ acting by $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: The representation you gave doesn't seem to work as the matrices do not satisfy the commutator relation $XY-YX = Y$.

Comment: I solved it! I did manage to construct a working higher-dimensional irrep for characteristic $p$. We find that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $X$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $X(Yv) = (\lambda+1)v$. Therefore, $X(Y^pv) = \lambda v = Xv$, so if we set $Y$ to be some matrix such that $Y^p = I$ the subspace spanned by $v, Yv, \ldots Y^{p-1}v$ is an irreducible representation of dimension $p$.

Comment: @RohilPrasad Glad you solved it. I think mine does work (remember we're working in characteristic $2$). In fact, I think it's the simplest special case of your construction.